# Javascript regex not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
words = ["hi2", "say3", "you1", "me1"],

regex1 = /[\S]{2,3}[1|2|3]/g,

window.word_text = function(){

    var data = document.getElementById("input").value.split(" ")

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 

        for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++){ 
            if (regex1.exec(data[i]) == words[j]){

                console.log("match");
            }
            else{
                console.log("no match")
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="input" type="text" onblur="word_text()">

</body>
</html>
```

When data[i] is a good match ("hi2") the instructions are not always executed so there appears to be an issue with my regex. Note that it does work perfectly without the g (multiple matches) but I need it because in the if statement "hi2" will be replaced by an array of 
things that have two or three letters and are followed by 1, 2  or 3. So I would need my data[i] to recognize "hi2say1" to match "hi2" and "say1".

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `exec` returns an array or null. But your goal is very unclear. Can you build a snippet with some proper code and precisely state the desired result ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's `data[i]`? Why are you comparing string with array?

Comment: Seeing as `/g` is causing the issue, and you're saying *not always*, it seems that you are having issues with how `exec` handles successive matches. Note that `regex1.exec` won't yield the same result every time, on successive calls with the same input, if the expression has the global flag. It is difficult, however, to give a good answer to what you should be doing, from the way your question is currently worded. [See the section on successive matches here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Would be useful to see some real code. It's pretty hard to figure out what you're doing with the code you've shown us.

Comment: Also, `[\S]` is redundant and can be reduced to just `\S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an expression with a global flag, `exec` will advance through the string on each successive call, and yield new matches. Each call will search from the beginning of the previous match.

At some point, you will reach the last match. Calling `exec` at this point will not find any more matches, and return `null`. The expressions `lastIndex` flag will be reset, and another call to `exec` will restart the search from scratch:

```js
regex1 = /[\S]{2,3}[1|2|3]/g
var input = 'hi2say1';
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(i, JSON.stringify(regex1.exec(input)));
```

The result of `exec` is intended to be iterated while it is not null, to allow you to inspect each successive match in a global expression. Since you're iterating through every word, you don't need to check every match in the expression at every iteration - you are explicitly searching for a single phrase at a time. That could be achieved much easier with a simple `indexOf`:

```js
var words = ["hi2", "say3", "you1", "me1"];
var data = 'say1hi2abc a1hi2'.split(" ");

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
  for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++){ 
    if (data[i].indexOf(words[j]) >= 0){
      console.log("MATCH!", data[i], "does contain", words[j]);
    } else {
      console.log("No match.", words[j], "was not found in", data[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic could be simplified. Looking at the code, you really are only interested in exact matches with the `words` list, so making a regular expression that only indicates whether it *could* match with a word is not so useful. The inner comparison you do, does not really need the regular expression.

Change:

```
regex1.exec(data[i]) == words[j]
```

To:

```
data[i] == words[j]
```

... and it will work. The console will show a lot of "no match" and some "match".

However, you could use a regular expression to make your code more efficient, but it should match exactly and only what is in the words list. Here is how you could do that:

```js
var words = ["hi2", "say3", "you1", "me1"],
    regex1 = new RegExp('\\b(' + words.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g'),
    input = document.getElementById("input"),
    output = document.getElementById("output");

function word_text(){
    var data = input.value,
        match = data.match(regex1);
    if (match) {
        output.textContent = "matches: " + match;
    }
    else{
        output.textContent = "no match";
    }
}

// link event handler, and run it now
input.oninput = word_text;
word_text();
```

```html
Type here: <input id="input" style="width:100%" value="can hi2 this is a test for you1">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What I forgot to say is that the input can also be something like "hi2?", "me1*" or "hi2say3", this is what's causing my troubles.

Comment: So what do you want to happen with these inputs? Would they be considered matches or not?

Comment: Yes, they would be considered matches.

Comment: What about these inputs:  `ahi2`, `5hi2`, `hi22`, `hi2a`. Should they match?

Comment: OK, you have accepted an answer, so I suppose the case is closed.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyways!